# How do I open UserForm in the active cell?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've got a UserForm that I'd like to start when I open the workbook and also in the range below. Also, always it has to be in the same place no matter what screen or computer it is.
But how do I do that?

I'll use a userform, because I will use multiple columns in the list box.

Range ("C35:K44"):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjGIB.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to use Activex Listbox, so I got as many colums I want and it's fixed in the range I want as well.

Answer (score 0):

As for opening the user form in the same place, this link should get you the information you need: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/formposition.htm. The below will run any code when the workbook is opened.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
'form opening code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, great tutorial! But it didn't work, through the link you shared I found the left and top position of the range that I wanted ("C35:K44"), but as soon as I open the workbook the form don't fix in the place I want. 
I'd like the form in that range and not to move in a single time.

Example: https://imgur.com/a/l6pKLvP